# Wix Toolset start WixUI installer GUI based on command line option

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3

I would like to have a command line option INVOKEINSTALL="YES"/"NO" while invoke my msi. If it's passed as yes, then use the build-in WixUI istaller (), otherwise just use the default.

The Wix Toolset version I am using is 3.11

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the installer is an .msi and not a burn .exe bundle, then you can use the built-in functionality of [msiexec](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/msiexec.html) to switch between different levels of UI:

```
msiexec.exe /i productinstaller.msi /qf
```

Installs the product using the full installer UI.
The "/qf" switch specifies that the installer should use the full UI provided. Alternatively, "/qb" or "/qn" can be used for the basic UI or for no UI respectively.

Comment: Thank you Calum, I am a newbie to Windows development world and I just find out by reading the msiexec help page today... I will delete this post  later today but  thank you for for answering that.